# SQLServer filtered index issue

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I did many searchs to find answer for my specific issue but didn't manage to find one..
Here is my problem:

I created a filtered index on a table (SQLServer) :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_FilteredIdx] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Type] ASC,
    [CreationDate] ASC
)
WHERE ([Statut]=N'CREATED'
```

What i see is that SQL requests such as :

```
select Id, CreationDate, [An other field not in the index] from MyTable
where Type='XXX' and CreationDate<'YYYY'
and Statut=N'CREATED'
```

use the filtered index (and a key lookup for other field) if 'XXX' is an existing value in the index OR a not existing value in the table (yes sounds very weird..)

If XXX does not exist in the index (no value with CREATED statut for example), but exists in the table, the execution plan turns to a 'clustered index scan' with awful performances (the table is big > 600 M rows) and finally returns empty result as expected...
(The total number of row with statut CREATED is very small compared to the whole table).

I saw that including the column used for filtering was recommended by microsoft :

"A column in the filtered index expression should be a key or included column in the filtered index definition if the column is in the query result set."

but i get the same issue with the column included in the index (and it seems very counter intuitive to add it when the filter criteria is a literal fixed value..).

The only way i found for this request to use the filtered index and get decent performance was to add the Statut column in the second position of the index...

(I also understand than depending on the selected fields and the cardinality of the result the engine may choose to use a clustered index scan to prevent a costly key lookup step.)

Does someone have an explanation for this behavior .. ?

Regards.

Comment: Clarification on the scenario where it table scans - does it still include a predicate for `Statut=N'Created'`?

Comment: For the "table scan" scenario the request is exactly the same and the predicate is visible on the clustered index scan operator in the execution plan.

Comment: I'm finally convinced it's an "issue" related to statistics on the index. But even knowing this, it's truly hell to guess the "Statut" must be included in the index at a given position to provide useful stats for the optimizer...